# Perl, run .exe in another window and get PID

Tags: windows, perl, parallel-processing

I have a directory who contains :

- script.pl
- app.exe

In my perl script, I want run the app.exe in another shell like this :

- I run the script.pl
- A shell open and execute commands in the perl script
- After a while, the perl script run the app.exe (and get the app.exe PID)
- **A new shell opening** and execute the app.exe. In the same time, the perl script continue his execution
- After a while, the perl script stop the app.exe (with the PID)

My questions :

1. How can I execute the app.exe **in another shell window** in "background mode" ? (the perl script execution and app.exe are 'parallel')
2. How can I get the PID of my app.exe when the perl script execute it ?

Thank you :)

Comment: On Windows, [`$pid=system(1,...)`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlport#system).

Comment: When I do that, I get the pid. However, the app.exe run on the same shell where I ran the perl script. I would like open a new shell where the app.exe is executed. (One shell for the perl script continue to be executed and one shell for the app.exe is executed)

Comment: `system(1,"START ...")`

Answer (score 0):

I´m new with perl but i think that you can solve with this.

My answer:

**Question 1**:You can test 2 ways.

Case 1:Directly with system command:

system("start app.exe");

Case 2:
Create a batch file just with the launch command and then execute with perl.

launchAPP.bat

---

```
@echo off
start app.exe
```

---

Perl code:

```
system("launchAPP.bat");
```

**Question 2**:You can test 2 ways also.

Depending on the architecture of your system.

x32:
There is in CPAN a library that can fits with your code. It uses windows C libraries to retrive the info.

Here is a link to CPAN library:
[Win32::Process::List](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-Process-List/List.pm)

x64 or x32:

You can use wmic:

```
wmic process where (Name like '%%app.exe%%' and CommandLine like '%%example%%') get ProcessId | more >> pid.txt
```

In perl:

```
system(wmic process where (Name like '%%app.exe%%' and CommandLine like '%%example%%') get ProcessId | more >> pid.txt);
```

It creates a file with pid of the process that you want to extract that you can read with perl easily.

I hope this helps.